# I want to set the size of one of the button inside grid layout in java

Tags: java

I am using a grid layout for my button panel and in grid layout all the components are by default of same size i want one of my button size to increase.please suggest me the way for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`bttn.setBounds(X,Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);`

bttn is a JButton object

Comment: I used this setBounds() method but it is not affecting the button size at all.

Comment: What have you written in `setBounds()` method? It is working fine for me.

Comment: I am using this as a setBounds(0,1,30,40)

Answer (score -1):

GridLayout is not support different sizes for components.
You can use GridBagLayout. It allows set custom size for one of components.